# MySQL trigger, change value before update conditionally

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to change a value conditionally on my trigger, but I've got an error.

My trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `defineBase` BEFORE INSERT ON `perguntas`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.per_base = 0 THEN
        SET NEW.per_base = (SELECT per_id FROM perguntas ORDER BY per_id DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;
    END IF;
END;
```

but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter to something else than `;`. Otherwise the trigger definition stops at the first `;`

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `defineBase` BEFORE INSERT ON `perguntas`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF NEW.per_base = 0 THEN
        SET NEW.per_base = (SELECT per_id FROM perguntas ORDER BY per_id DESC LIMIT 1) + 1;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. My SQL code before is just like this (without delimiter):

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_created_time BEFORE INSERT
ON contact FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.created=NOW();
END
```

Then, after i add the following DELIMITER // and close it with the same //

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER update_created_time BEFORE INSERT
ON contact FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.created=NOW();
END //
```

It works. I hope it can help someone in the future...